# Measuring mass density of electrons in the universe

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, cosmology, mass, measurements

Pardon me if the question is too naive, but only baryon and dark matter masses are considered while making measurements of the mass density in the universe.
What I am interested to know is how small is the total mass of electrons, relative to the other two that it was safely ignored from calculations in the Standard Model of cosmology?

Comment: By conservation of charge there are as many electrons as protons . the mass of the electron is about $1/2 MeV/c^2$, of the proton about 1000 Mev. Consider also the neutrons who are about 100 MeV . The estimated numbers do not have the accuracy to "see" the electron masses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume the universe is electrically neutral (it might not be completely neutral, but it is [neutral to a large degree](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/5896/is-there-any-theory-or-observational-evidence-that-our-universe-is-electrically)) then there are roughly the same number of protons as there are electrons. Because the mass of protons (and neutrons) is about 1836 times that of electrons, it's safe to assume that the contribution from electrons is negligible.